# Eclipse live management

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently using Eclipse for a Java application I am creating. I find it very irritating when I'm trying to create the GUI and I have to keep launching the application to check every element is in the correct place. Is there any sort of live management system that would allow me to see the editing happening live as I change positions of components, etcetera? It sounds highly unlikely as I have never come across such a thing, but it sure does sound helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I used it many years ago and dont remember the exactly name.

You should install a plugin called "Matisse for Eclipse" (but the code it generates to a simple GUI is awful)

Theres others too you should look for Visual Interface Builders.

Comment: It isn't some sort of Drag and Drop is it? I prefer to type the code by hand

Comment: Ohh.. those aew D&D builders, in your case then, you should design your screens to be independent and instantiate the one that you wanna see fast.